# complex c# object accessible in all windows store app pages

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a list of StorageFiles and want to make it accessible in all windows store app pages.
I tried with Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings and Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings but those are supporting  runtime data types only. Also, I don't want to use Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue and navigation parameter.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define them as global variables in your `App.xaml.cs` file.

In `App.xaml.cs`

```
public static List<StorageFile> globalFile;
```

You can then access it in your apps pages with

```
App.globalFile
```

You will still have to load these files from somewhere when your app is run before you can use them though.